# Can't parse the List<String> data Screen A to Screen B. Using same Viewmodel in both screens

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

*Problem statement: I'm expecting that from this code I can share List data first screen to another screen.*

**Stacktrace**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/post/filter/SnapshotStateList(value=[/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20240201-WA0010.jpg, /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20240210-WA0001.mp4, /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20240210-WA0002.mp4, /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20240210-WA0000.mp4])@57386330 } cannot be found in the navigation graph ComposeNavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x78d845ec) route=home}
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1815)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:2221)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:2216)
> at com.sociallab.feature.post.createPost.PostCreateScreenKt$PostCreateScreen$1$2.invoke(PostCreateScreen.kt:95)
> at com.sociallab.feature.post.createPost.PostCreateScreenKt$PostCreateScreen$1$2.invoke(PostCreateScreen.kt:91)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableNode$clickPointerInput$3.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:655)

**Mainactivity.kt**

```
@Composable
private fun MyNavigationHost(
    modifier: Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    NavHost(
        navController,
        modifier = modifier,
        startDestination = AppRoute.Home.route
    ) {
        postNavGraph(navController)

    }
}
```

**postNavGraph.kt**

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.postNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    composable(PostRoute.Create.route) {
        PostCreateScreen(
            navController,
            hiltViewModel()
        )
    }
    composable(PostRoute.Filter.route) {
        FilterPostScreen(
            navController,
            hiltViewModel()
        )
    }
  
}
```

**PostRoute.kt**

```
sealed class PostRoute(route: String, routePlaceholder: String) : AppRoute(route, routePlaceholder) {
    data object Create : PostRoute("$PREFIX/create","$PREFIX/create" )
    data object Filter : PostRoute("$PREFIX/filter","$PREFIX/filter")
    data object Final:PostRoute("$PREFIX/final","$PREFIX/final")
    data object Music:PostRoute("$PREFIX/music","$PREFIX/music")
//    data class MediaList:  PostRoute("$PREFIX/filter","$PREFIX/filter")
//    data object MediaList(val data: List<String>) : PostRoute("$PREFIX/filter/$data","$PREFIX/filter/data")
    /*data class MediaList(val data: List<String>) : PostRoute("$PREFIX/filter/{${data}}", "$PREFIX/filter/{${data}}")*/

}
```

**ViewModel.kt**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MediaViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

private val _selectedMediaList = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())
val selectedMediaList: StateFlow<List<String>> = _selectedMediaList

fun updateSelectedMedia(media: List<String>) {
    _selectedMediaList.value = media
}
}
```

**Screen A.kt**
on Next button click listner

```
viewModel.updateSelectedMedia(selectedMediaList)
//                    navController.navigate(PostRoute.MediaList(selectedMediaList).route)
  navController.navigate(PostRoute.Filter.route)
```

**Screen B.kt**
Fetch data

```
    val selectedMediaList by viewModel.selectedMediaList.collectAsState()


 // Update the ViewModel when selectedMediaList changes
    LaunchedEffect(selectedMediaList) {
        viewModel.updateSelectedMedia(selectedMediaList)
    }
```

Comment: Are you passing the list as part of your navigation routes? I see that the code related is commented.

Comment: Problem is solved you can review my answer. @tomerpacific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My only problem was to share list of string using route and this is how I solved.**

And this solution of viewmodel i did my changes for solution.

**Navgraph**

```
composable(PostRoute.Create.route) {
    val viewModel: FilterScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    PostCreateScreen(
        navController,
        viewModel
    )
}
composable(PostRoute.MediaList(emptyList()).routePlaceholder) {
    val viewModel: FilterScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    FilterPostScreen(
        navController,
        viewModel
    )
}
```

**PostRoute**

```
data class MediaList(
    val data: List<String>
) : PostRoute(
    "$PREFIX/filters?references=${
        URLEncoder.encode(
            data.joinToString(separator = ","),
            "UTF-8"
        )
    }",
    "$PREFIX/filters?references={references}"
)
```

**viewmodel**

```
val data: List<String>
    get() {
        val joinedString = savedStateHandle.get<String>("references") ?: ""
        return if (joinedString.isNotEmpty()) {
            joinedString.split(",").map { it.replace("+", " ") }
        } else {
            listOf()
        }
    }
```

**Screen B**

```
sliderList = viewModel.data
```

mention viewmodel and then get data in list parameter

**Screen A**

```
navController.navigate(PostRoute.MediaList(selectedMediaList).route)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the stacktrace:
NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/post/filter/**SnapshotStateList...** cannot be found in the navigation graph ComposeNavGraph

It seems like you're also **passing the list in the nav arguments**. Make sure that you're not passing the list there.

If you need to share the list between those 2 screens you need to pass the same instance of viewmodel in both screens.

**hiltViewModel() will create a new instace each time** that's why you'll get an empty list in each screen.

So you need to **create a single instance of viewmodel** and pass it as parameter in screens like this.

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.postNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    val viewModel: MediaViewModel = hiltViewModel() // A single viewmodel instance here
    composable(PostRoute.Create.route) {
        PostCreateScreen(
            navController,
            viewModel
        )
    }
    composable(PostRoute.Filter.route) {
        FilterPostScreen(
            navController,
            viewModel
        )
    }
}
```

You can use this viewmodel in any number of screens and hold the data as it's basically the same instance.

Comment: I'm still didnt get value in next screen

Comment: here is what written in ScreenB '''    val selectedMediaList by viewModel.selectedMediaList.collectAsState()
'''

Comment: Just directly print the viewmodel.hashcode() in logs at both of the screens which will give you a value to check if both of that are the same instance or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help @hiren . you can check my answer how i solved my problem.